# Free Windows GUI text editor supporting Regular Expressions, for programmers?

Tags: windows, regex, user-interface, text-editor

Looking for a ***free*** Windows GUI text editor that supports **solid**<sup>1</sup> regular expressions for its Find/Replace features, for programmers to use.

Familiar with Vim, Ed, Emacs, etc. Not looking for a command-based editor. Will give chosen editor to team members already familiar with Regular Expressions, but don't want learning curve incurred to use the editor itself.

**1**: "solid" meaning: the newest syntax or features implemented.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what **solid** means? Including "look arounds"?

Comment: Added edit to question to clarify.

Comment: There's a version of vim for MS Windows that has a GUI.  I use it frequently, and sometimes even use the GUI controls.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/576403/101936

Comment: Regular Expression are in active development and there are comming new features every month ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The [Zeus Lite](http://www.zeusedit.com/lite) editor implements a *Perl* style of regular expression and it is free.

Comment: free i.e. you are the product

Answer (score 4):

[Notepad RE](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/notepadre.aspx) (PCRE regex support) and [Programmers Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/features/) (PERL regex support) have both worked out really well for me. The former is a good replacement for Notepad.

Notepad++ is useful for less complex regular expressions.

Comment: Just realized the question is a year old but hopefully this answer is helpful to those looking for a good regex editor

Comment: Note that this editor uses the [Boost regex library](http://www.boost.org/) and not the [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/) - Both are "Perl compatible", but there are differences.

Comment: Programmers' Notepad worked for me until I found that it's Search function does not support Unicode!

Comment: And Notepad RE Replace dialog doesn't work when you click the Replace button!

Answer (score 4):

[EditPadLite 7](http://www.editpadlite.com/) (the free-for-non-commercial-use scaled-down version of EditpadPro) now provides regex search and replace.

It uses JGSoft's very powerful regex engine.

**Edit 2012-03-12** [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) is a very popular free editor, but in the past did not have powerful regex (so I have never really used it). However, as of version 6, it now incorporates the very powerful and stable [PCRE regex library](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pcre.org%2F&ei=Z14_UZGdDs7WrQGg8YH4BQ&usg=AFQjCNHIwpL43koPPc3UQxDFZZarLV54nQ&sig2=o21QxKp7EE5pcs9VZlQa0Q&bvm=bv.43287494,d.aWM). Although I'm a die-hard EditPadPro user, I may need to take a second look...

Answer (score 3):

[EditPad Pro](http://www.regular-expressions.info/editpadpro.html) seems to have it all. Although commercial, you can try for free.

As a free alternative, I use [ConTEXT](http://www.contexteditor.org/) from time to time when I'm on Windows. Although it does not support look-arounds, almost all other PCRE features are supported. It's a nice lightweight text editor with tons of syntax highlighters available.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me I wanted a free one. I just edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @John K: Notepad++'s regex engine is to EditPadPro's regex engine what a 20-year-old VW Bug is to a Mercedes 500 SLK. Is your programmers' productivity worth nothing? You'll make up for your investment in no time at all if your programmers need to use regular expressions seriously.

Comment: As of June 2011, [EditpadLite 7](http://www.editpadlite.com/) provides regex just like its big brother.

Comment: EditPad Pro is truly an excellent editor.  I know it's nice getting things for free, but if this is something you plan to use every day to make a living consider dropping some cash on the proper tools.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer in the negative (and only a year late):

There are certain editors which are very good in many respects, but that have very poor support for regular expressions: "SciTE", "Programmer's Notepad" a "Notepad++" (which are all free). These are all based on the "Scintilla" library, which has a regex engine that does not even support alternation.

Hence, if regexes are important to you, then you should probably avoid those.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a lot of the suggested programs listed above, but to date the only free text editor I've found that has **robust** support (i.e., no bugs, almost all functionality) for regular expressions is [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/).

All the others have some wierd limitation one way or the other, like the inability to search for newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `notepad++`, which is free and supports all kinds of regexy goodness.

Get **[the PortableApps version](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable)** and you can keep it on a keydrive all the time -- handy for a mobile dev platform.

Comment: @jdk, note that notepad++ has no look arounds.

Comment: @Bart K: I'll keep my fingers crossed for that feature. Until then the team has a solid regex GUI editor that suits their needs well.

Comment: @Bart K, it's GPL licensed, so anybody could potentially add that.

Comment: notepad++ regex support is limited to expressions within a line !

Comment: "Notepad++" is based on "Scintilla", and therefore has poor regex support: not even alternation is implemented. I too am looking for a good free programmer's editor, but none has all the features I want. One of the better offerings is "SciTE" (highly configurable through configuration files), but that is also based on "Scintilla" and thus suffers from the same fault. (I'm now watching the "Emerald Editor" project with interest, but am still looking elsewhere.)

Comment: Get EditPad Pro Trial Edition, it has a nag screen. that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a free text GUI text editor with full or comprehensive regex support (including lookahead/lookbehind assertions) AND the ability to search across multiple files.  Zeus Lite has support but it froze with a very large set of files.  For my GUI text editor needs, there's a bevy out there.  When I'm searching through a very large set of files with comprehensive regex support and I want a FREE program, I use TextCrawler.

[TestCrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/textcrawler) is NOT a GUI text editor, but for my needs, it serves a complimentary role to your GUI text editor of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Another good one that I use - I like it better than notepad++ and ConTEXT - is [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/pspad.htm)
It has a great set of features and can load larger files than notepad++.

A REALLY fully featured light-weight editor that I use to replace notepad - but has many of the features of PSPad including regular expression search is [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)

Comment: I LOVE Notepad2, but its regex support is again limited to 1 line regex !

Answer (score 0):

I have often used regex find/replace in Netbeans in the past. It can handle multiple files
(filenames can be specified by regexp too!)